# Php namespaces with functions

Tags: php, namespaces

I have a directory `include`. In this directory, I have only one dir: `HQF`. In this directory, I have many files where I always declare them belonging to the `HQF` namespace like this:

```
<?php
namespace HQF;
class MyClass
{
}
```

And the file is called "`MyClass.php`". I'm trying to stick "a bit" to [PSR0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/fr/PSR-0.md).

Everything works fine, and I've made my autoloader like this:

```
function __autoload($className)
{
    $className = ltrim($className, '\\');
    $fileName  = '';
    $namespace = '';
    if ($lastNsPos = strripos($className, '\\')) {
        $namespace = substr($className, 0, $lastNsPos);
        $className = substr($className, $lastNsPos + 1);
        $fileName  = str_replace('\\', DS, $namespace).DS;
    }
    $fileName .= str_replace('_', DS, $className).'.php';
    $fileName = 'include/'.$fileName;
    require $fileName;
}
```

So when I need a class I just have to do:  `$m = new \HQF\MyClass();` and it works like a charm, including automagically the file "`include/HQF/MyClass.php`"

I have a problem with "pure" functions.

I've made a file called "`include/HQF/mb_utils.php`" where I want to put my `mb_xxx` function. NB: no classes, *only functions*.

I've tried all the following things without success:

- `$test=\HQF\mb_ucname('calling HQF/mb_ucname...')`;
- `$test=\mb_ucname('calling HQF/mb_ucname...')`;
- `use \HQF\mb_utils`; and then the two tests above;

None of them work. What am I missing?

Comment: You're missing the fact that \_\_autoload() ___only___ works with classes, not with functions, namespacing is irrelevant... if you want to autoload functions, you need to do this via regular (manual) includes

Comment: I'd be interested in any responses suggesting how to approach this, because I'm currently trying to fathom a solution myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm relying on Mark Baker's comment.

So here's my workaround: I've made a file named `Mb.php` and in it, a class named "`Mb`" (for 'multibytes') and I've put all my mutibytes functions like this:

```
<?php
namespace HQF;

class Mb
{
    static public function ucfirst(&$string, $e ='utf-8')
    {
        /* blabla */
    }
    static public function ucname($string, $e ='utf-8')
    {
        /* blabla */
    }
}
```

And then I call them like this:

```
$mystring_to_change = \HQF\Mb::ucname($original_name);
```

This is the only way I've found, I dont know if it's the best one... any suggestion welcome.